# How to tell the compiler to user binary search

Tags: python, binary-search

I am working on the algorithm of a project Euler problem. In this, I am processing a large list of numbers with possibly millions of entries in the list. I know beforehand that the list is sorted and I want to check if a particular element is in it or not. I can do it like:

```
if element in array:
    #do something
else:
    # do something else
```

or like:

```
if((array.index(element)>=0):
    # do something
else: 
    # do something else
```

But I know it searches for the element linearly, which takes much time. It pains me that even if the list is sorted, it searches for it linearly. Is there a way that I can tell the compiler to search for the element using binary search, like a default parameter like:

```
if(array.index(element, binary_search=False):
    #do something
```

so that I can make the second parameter to `True` and it works as expected. Or do I have to write the `binary search function` by myself and use it instead of the builtin `index` method or the `in` operator?

I am new to Python. Please bear with my ignorance. I searched for it extensively but couldn't find the exact answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using `set`

Comment: could you please expand on your idea. As far as I know, sets are used to remove duplicate items and to perform mathematical set operations like intersection, union etc. I am not aware of the search facility in set. Please elaborate.

Comment: You should definitely check the duplicate URL first. Anyway, `set` is internally hashed, therefore looking up an element in `set` (ideally) works like indexing an array and takes constant time (i.e. `O(1)`) which is faster than `O(log(n))` of binary search.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs and patience. This helped a lot.